# Handling different screen sizes in image carousel

Tags: onsen-ui

Is there some way to provide different image sizes for the carousel for different screen sizes ? I understand the CSS media query can get this information to provide different CSS settings for different devices/screens, but I don't see anyway to pass this information into the carousel. For a full-screen carousel this seems to mean it only works properly on devices matching the image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the images take up a certain percentage of the screen by scaling them.

```
ons-carousel-item {
  text-align: center;
}

ons-carousel-item img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

And the carousel:

```
<ons-carousel overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen var="carousel">
  <ons-carousel-item>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </ons-carousel-item>
  <ons-carousel-item>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/700x100">
  </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```